# Getting data from Nodejs to html

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to get data from my nodejs application to my html page. I've looked at express and `socket.io`. To my knowledge the data the transfer has to be transferred to a file on the socket e.g. **localhost:8080**. I want data to be shown on my web server localhost no port.

Is there anyway I can do this?

```
<!-- index.html -->
<!doctype html>  
<html lang="en">  
    <head>
    <script>  
 var socket = io.connect();
 socket.on('connect', function(data) {
    socket.emit('join', 'Hello World from client');
 });
 socket.on('broad', function(data) {
         $('#future').append(data+ "<br/>");
   });

 $('form').submit(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     var message = $('#chat_input').val();
     socket.emit('messages', message);
 });

  client.on('changeXvalue', function(data) {
         $("#future1").text(data);
   });
</script>  
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        <div id="future"></div>
        <div id="future1"></div>
        <form id="form" id="chat_form">
            <input id="chat_input" type="text">
            <input type="submit" value="Send">
        </form>
         <script src="./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="./socket.io.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

App.js

```
    // app.js
    var express = require('express');  
    var app = express();  
    var server = require('http').createServer(app);  
    var io = require('socket.io')(server);

    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules'));  
    app.get('/', function(req, res,next) {  
        res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
    });

    io.on('connection', function(client) {  
        console.log('Client connected...');

        client.on('join', function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        });

        client.on('messages', function(data) {
               client.emit('broad', data);
               client.broadcast.emit('broad',data);
        });
        var data = "test";
        socket.emit('changeXvalue', data);

    });

    server.listen(4200);
```

Comment: Hi @Kong, Can you post some code you have tried out?

Comment: I havent really got round to posting code, as i dont know where to start. Ive been mostly looking at tutorials @Varun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple you should have to use a socket.io client library in your HTML page

Follow the below steps to build the Node JS using socket.io

```
$ mkdir socket-app
$ cd socket-app
$ npm init

$ npm install socket.io express --save

$ npm install jquery --save
```

**Express Server**

```
// app.js
var express = require('express');  
var app = express();  
var server = require('http').createServer(app);  
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules'));  
app.get('/', function(req, res,next) {  
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

server.listen(4200);
```

**HTML**

```
<!-- index.html -->
<!doctype html>  
<html lang="en">  
    <head>
    <script>  
 var socket = io.connect();
 socket.on('connect', function(data) {
    socket.emit('join', 'Hello World from client');
 });
 socket.on('broad', function(data) {
         $('#future').append(data+ "<br/>");
   });

 $('form').submit(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     var message = $('#chat_input').val();
     socket.emit('messages', message);
 });
</script>  
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        <div id="future"></div>
        <form id="form" id="chat_form">
            <input id="chat_input" type="text">
            <input type="submit" value="Send">
        </form>
         <script src="/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**run it using**

```
node app.js
```

Let's us add this before server listen

```
 io.on('connection', function(client) {  
    console.log('Client connected...');

    client.on('join', function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });

    client.on('messages', function(data) {
           client.emit('broad', data);
           client.broadcast.emit('broad',data);
    });

});
```

Comment: Ok I got this setup, Now how would I actually show data from the ndoejs script. Eg I have a var called x and its = 0. How would I get that to the html?

Comment: if var is initially x in node js and you emitting data from client then just in socket.on you can change that data, you can make x=emitted value from client, for that as well this code only the base if didn't find answer then please share your code then might be able to give you answer

Comment: Ive literally got the code you gave above, I want to display a variable from the nodejs file on the html page

Comment: then you can use the template engine Pug.js (Jade) or you can use angular or react js also for data binding

Comment: and how do i do that?

Comment: please confirm,  what is your preferred technology? so that I can give the answer below

Comment: When you say prefered technology what do you mean? If you asking like socket io and express. I really have not preference, i just want it to work

Comment: html page or template cannot be changed without the jade-like template engine or jquery or angular or react js

Comment: check my answer 2 the node js value can be passed via socket and can be changed in the HTML page using jQuery

Answer (score 0):

You can use try this jQuery to change HTML page value

Add this in index.html

```
<!doctype html>  
<html lang="en">  
    <head>
        <script src="./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="./socket.io.js"></script>
        <script>

 var socket = io.connect("http://localhost:4200");
 socket.on('connect', function(data) {
    socket.emit('join', 'Hello World from client');
 });
 socket.on('broad', function(data) {
         $('#future').append(data+ "<br/>");
   });

 $('form').submit(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     var message = $('#chat_input').val();
     socket.emit('messages', message);
 });

  client.on('changeXvalue', function(data) {
         $("#future1").text(data);
   });
</script>  
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        <div id="future"></div>
        <div id="future1"></div>
        <form id="form" id="chat_form">
            <input id="chat_input" type="text">
            <input type="submit" value="Send">
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

Server-side code to emit x value

```
 // app.js
    var express = require('express');  
    var app = express();  
    var server = require('http').createServer(app);  
    var io = require('socket.io')(server);

    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules'));  
    app.get('/', function(req, res,next) {  
        res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
    });

    io.on('connection', function(client) {  
        console.log('Client connected...');

        client.on('join', function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        });

        client.on('messages', function(data) {
               client.emit('broad', data);
               client.broadcast.emit('broad',data);
        });
        var data = "test";
        socket.emit('changeXvalue', data);

    });

    server.listen(4200);
```

Comment: This still doesnt work for me. I want the simplest way of getting data from a node webserver to my apache webserver. For example on node y=2. I want my js on the apache webserver to know that

Comment: You are missing something please add your code in question so that can give you the best

Comment: Ive said this already, i just have ur base code atm. but ill add now

Comment: check the answer you added scripts before the scripting logic

Comment: you should mention the server as well to connect with socket